# Timezone issues with Redshift COPY from Parquet

Tags: amazon-redshift, parquet

I am loading a Parquet file into Redshift.  The Parquet file has a timestamp column.

Question: Is there any way to specify what timezone to use as context when converting the Parquet timestamp (a specific instant in time) to a `TIMESTAMP` in Redshift (an abstract date/time without timezone context)

Put differently:

When I INSERT `'2019-01-01 00:00'::timestamp` into a `TIMESTAMP` column, I get exactly `2019-01-01 00:00` back, no matter what my session timezone is.  I would imagine CSV is similar.

When I load from Parquet, the only way I can get `2019-01-01 00:00` into a `TIMESTAMP` column is if the Parquet timestamp represents `2019-01-01 00:00 _UTC_`.    I would like to get the same result in Redshift with a timestamp like  `2019-01-01 00:00 _EDT_` in Parquet (which would be `04:00` or `05:00` UTC)

Comment: Is your destination field in Redshift a `TIMESTAMP` or a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE`? If the source does not have a timezone, it's probably preferable to use the latter.

Comment: Neither source nor destination have timezone info.  Source is a Parquet timestamp, destination is Redshift `TIMESTAMP` (without timezone; with timezone is `TIMESTAMPTZ`)

Comment: Have you tried playing with [`SET timezone`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_timezone_config.html) to set a default, or [AT TIME ZONE Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_AT_TIME_ZONE.html) to convert the timestamp?

Comment: Yes, `set timezone` has no impact on timestamps without timezone.  I can of course convert the timestamp but at that point I can no longer load the data directly from Parquet but have to do some transformation within Redshift